# SQL Query for Login Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When a user login with his Vendor_ID and password, he will redirect to 2 different pages based upon the conditions. If he already register in the site and his registration is approved by the web admin, he will redirect to 'RegPage1.aspx' otherwise to 'ApprovalStatus.aspx'. If the user enter the wrong Vendor_ID or Password it will throw the error message as 'Enter valid VendorID or Password'. So i wrote the C# code like below. **It works fine** but anyone can help me to simply this by merge the two SQL queries, check the vendor_ID availabilty in 'User_Info' table and ApprovalStatus check in 'Company_Info' table ?

```
    protected void BtnHomeUserSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());  
    try      
    {             
      if ((txtHomeUsername.Text == "") || (txtHomePassword.Text == ""))        
      {               
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert ('Enter valid  VendorID or Password');", true); 
      }             
      else           
      {       
         var da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from User_Info where Vendor_ID='" +  txtHomeUsername.Text.Trim() + "'", SqlCon);                
        var dt1 = new DataTable();          
        da1.Fill(dt1);         
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)        
        {            
         var da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Company_Info where Approval_Status='NO' AND Vendor_ID='" + txtHomeUsername.Text.Trim() + "'", SqlCon);        
              var dt2 = new DataTable();    
              da2.Fill(dt2);            

         if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)       
         {            
           string url = "ApprovalStatus.aspx";     
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callfunction", "alert('Your Vendor ID is already registered');window.location.href = '" + url + "';", true);  
         }        
         else          
         {                      
             Response.Redirect("RegPage1.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode (txtHomeUsername.Text));        
         }       
     }          
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Enter valid  VendorID or Password');", true);     
         }      
    }       
   finally   
   {      
    SqlCon.Close();    
   }       
   }
```

Comment: Your code is susceptible to a SQL Injection attack, please up about this. I wrote about it on my blog, which may be a good place to start: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2005/04/23/sql-injection-attacks-and-some-tips-on-how-to-prevent-them/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [protect your code from SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

If you want to:

> merge the two SQL queries, check the vendor_ID availabilty in 'User_Info' table and ApprovalStatus check in 'Company_Info' table

Then `JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User_Info ui
INNER JOIN Company_Info ci On ui.VendorID = ci.VendorID
WHERE ci.Approval_Status='NO'
AND ui.Vendor_ID = @vendor_IdParam
```

Comment: This won't work since for a valid Login/Registration the logic states that 1) A row must exist in the User_Info table and 2) a row must NOT exist in the Company_Info table ("alert('Your Vendor ID is already registered')")

Comment: @anAgent, but the OP tested for `dt2.Rows.Count > 0` in his code. That's why I joined the two tables this way.

Comment: The Link you given to protect from SQL Injection is pointout that it Applies To
•ASP.NET version 1.1
•ASP.NET version 2.0
but i am using .NET framework 4.0, so i don't care about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following query which is JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM user_info a JOIN company_info b on a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id WHERE a.vendor_id='txt_username' AND b.approval_status='NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Great points made by @mahmoud-gamal and @colin-mackay - get rid of your code that allows SQL injection. 
**DISCLAIMER** I've not tested this and is written from memory, but it should give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

To answer your question, it would look something like this.

**Logic**
1) Get user from User_Info table and ***LEFT JOIN*** on the Company_info table. 
**result:** 
IF no rows returned, then login/registration is not valid.
IF "any" rows, THEN check to see if there is an associated record in the Company_info (null value). If NOT "NullOrEmpty", the login/registration IS VALID. ELSE vendor is already registered.

```
    using(SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()) {
        var sqlString = "SELECT u.UserID, c.CompanyID FROM User_Info u LEFT JOIN Company_Info c ON c.VendorID = u.VendorID WHERE u.Vendor_ID = @p_VendorID AND c.Approval_Status='NO'";

        var da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, SqlCon);  
        da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p_VendorID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);
        da1.SelectCommand.Parameters["@p_VendorID"].Value = txtHomeUsername.Text.Trim();

        var dt1 = new DataTable(); 
        da1.Fill(dt1); 
        if(da1.Rows.Any()){     
            string userId = string.Empty;
            string companyId = string.Empty;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows){ 
                 userId = row["name"].ToString();
                 companyId = row["description"].ToString();
             }
             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyId)) {
                string url = "ApprovalStatus.aspx";     
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callfunction", "alert('Your Vendor ID is already registered');window.location.href = '" + url + "';", true);  
             } else {
                Response.Redirect("RegPage1.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode (txtHomeUsername.Text));  
             }          
        } else {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Enter valid VendorID or Password');", true);                 
        }

    }
```